# How to submit p:selectOneMenu value on ajax change event?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

Here's my code:

```
<h:form>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="handlerSelect" value="#{caseController.case.handler}" style="width:182px">
        <f:selectItems value="#{handlerController.findAllHandlers()}"
            var="handlerSelect" itemLabel="#{handlerSelect.name}"
            itemValue="#{handlerSelect}" />
        <p:ajax event="change"listener="#{caseController.changeHandler(handlerSelect)}"/>
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

As I change the value and the ajax event is triggered and it calls the `changeHandler` method, the `changeHandler` method gets null as parameter. It should be the selected handler person. Why is it null?

**UPDATE:** I had forgotten to put that component within h:form tags... but now that I got those added, I get a conversion error: `Conversion Error setting value '(Handler:2)' for 'null Converter'.`

Comment: The value is set in `#{caseController.case.handler}` by the ajax request... so why the need to pass it on? http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/ajax/dropdown.xhtml

Comment: I believe this may still apply? https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/defaultCommand.xhtml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay the main reason was originally that the component wasn't inside h:form-tags and secondly I had to use omnifaces converter to fix the conversion error. So in the end the working code looked like this:

```
    <h:form>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="handlerSelect" value="#{caseController.case.handler}" 
            converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsIndexConverter" style="width:182px">
            <f:selectItems value="#{handlerController.findAllHandlers()}"
                var="handlerSelect" itemLabel="#{handlerSelect.name}"
                itemValue="#{handlerSelect}" />
            <p:ajax event="change"listener="#{caseController.changeHandler(handlerSelect)}"/>
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </h:form>
```